# Dual Boot TrueCrypt Encrypted Windows and Linux with Grub workaround?

Tags: windows, linux, grub, multi-boot, truecrypt

The Major issue of not being able to dual-boot on TrueCrypt disc encryption systems won't get out of my mind.

My idea is, wouldn't it be possible to create an encrypted HDD with an Windows system on it on a slave HDD and install Linux on another main HDD, then point with grub to the TrueCrypt bootloader as an option in grub boot process?

Maybe you would need to take out the encrypted slave HDD of the PC before installing Linux to not interfere with the TrueCrypt mbr.

Would this work in theory? And how would I make sure that Grub stays superior after the encrypted drive with the TrueCrypt mbr is back in the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/358582/55246), basically you install Grub to the root partition of the linux install instead of the mbr and press escape to skip the Truecrypt password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that requires grub to be in the MBR of any specific disk (because your BIOS gives you a choice). You could have it on another drive or even a USB stick or CD. The only question is whether you can chainload TrueCrypt and my guess would be you can.

A little Google research brings up the same few posts all repeating the same misunderstanding of the issue. If you install Grub2 on the **SAME** MBR/drive as TrueCrypt then yes they will conflict (parts of TrueCrypt get overridden but then the same is true of Microsofts MBR install). I can't find anything saying that using different MBRs is a problem (unless you already corrupted your TrueCrypt MBR).